# PyQt Error: qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

При попытке компилировать созданное по туториалу простейшее оконное приложение на Python, в консоли выводит следующее сообщение:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "E:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\plugins\platforms"
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: minimal (from E:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\plugins\platforms), offscreen (from E:\Python35\Lib\site-
packages\PyQt5\plugins\platforms), windows (from E:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\plugins\platforms).
```

Папку `/platforms` перенес в папку проекта. Не помогло.

Переменную окружения указывал на эту самую папку `/platforms`. Тоже не помогло.

С каким бубном еще поплясать, чтобы все заработало? :с

Comment: Python - интерпретируемый язык, его скрипты не компилируются. Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, ссылку на тот туториал